# Some nice theorem to find the value of serie

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, big-list

I know a lot of techniques to show that a serie converge or diverge (Cauchy condensation test, Abel's test, comparision with an integrale, root test, ratio test...).

On the other hand I know nothing about caculating the value of a serie. Is there any theorems that may help ?

From now on I know the following :

- integrale test can be combine with squeeze theorem
- geometric serie

For example in this [[How to prove $\lim \limits_{x \to 1^-} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{n²} = \frac{1}{2} \ $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2620229/how-to-prove-lim-limits-x-to-1-sum-limits-n-0-infty-1nxn%C2%B2]) there are talking about :

- Herglotz' trick
- Weierstrass products.
- ...

So I would like to know if there are some other nice theorem or slick techniques to find the value of a serie.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this regard, series are much like integrals: you need knowledge and, even more, ingenuity and experience.

Some basic Theorems, besides those you cited, are:
 - [Indefinite Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum);
 - [Summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts);
 - [(Discrete) Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution);
 - [Partial Fractions Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition);
 - [Binomial Tranform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform) and others;
 - [Gosper's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper's_algorithm) and [Hypergeometric Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function);
 - [Abel's Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_binomial_theorem)
and many others

Comment: +1 for Gosper's Algorithm - found this a great presentation of why it works for WZ method: http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/slides/wilf80-slides.pdf
@auhasard well word a read if you have a chance. Came across the method in a nice compendium called Irresistible Integrals think this is a free pdf: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242969356_Irresistible_integrals_symbolics_analysis_and_experiments_in_the_evaluation_of_integrals- plenty of material in here!

Comment: (hoho pls ignore the bogus link, this is the book I meant if interested: [Irresistible Integrals, Symbolics, Experiments, Evaluation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Irresistible-Integrals-Symbolics-Experiments-Evaluation/dp/0521796369)

Comment: @Mehness: thanks for indicating these interesting publications. I'll try and get through them.

Comment: No problem sir, the book is definitely just sth to dip into if interested it's pretty hefty!

Comment: @GCab Thank you ! This is actually what I was looking for, now it's time to train !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a good approach and if you mentioned this but it would add another possible approach which I posted on the linked question.

Consider

$$
F(y+1)-F(y) = e^{i\pi y} x^{y^2} = e^{i \pi y -ay^2} = f,
$$

Take fourier transform of this and solve e.g.
$$
\hat F(s) = \frac{\hat f(s)}{e^{is} - 1}
$$
 Note that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n} F(i+1)-F(i) = - F(0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} F(n+1) - c \int \mathcal{F}(f)(s)\,ds = - c \int \mathcal{F}(f)(s)\,ds,
$$ under the assumption $\lim_{n\to\infty} F(n+1) = 0$

For the example above it turns out the fourier transform turns into a delta measure as we approach $x\to 1$ and this might be an approach that is tractable and lead to convergence proof and limit calculation.

Comment: I think you meant $n=\infty$ in your sum. Otherwise there's an extra term $F(n+1)$, .

Comment: thanks! I'll fix it